# Assignment has more non-singleton rhs dimensions than non-singleton subscripts error

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array

```
BE2A = 2*0.3048;
BE2B = 2*0.3048;
BETA = 0;

for i = 1:50

        for j = 1:i

            for k = 1:(i+1-j)

                % 1st quadrant
                BEXC(i,j,k,1) = i*0+j*0+(0.5+(k-1))*BE2A*cos(BETA/180*pi);
                BEYC(i,j,k,1) = i*0+j*0+(0.5+(k-1))*BE2A*sin(BETA/180*pi);
                BEZC(i,j,k,1) = i*0+(0.5+(j-1))*BE2B+k*0;
                BE2A(i,j,k,1) = BE2A+i*0+j*0+k*0;
                BE2B(i,j,k,1) = BE2B+i*0+j*0+k*0;
                ANGLE(i,j,k,1) = BETA+i*0+j*0+k*0;

                % 2nd quadrant
                BEXC(i,j,k,2) = i*0+j*0-(0.5+(k-1))*BE2A*cos(BETA/180*pi);
                BEYC(i,j,k,2) = i*0+j*0-(0.5+(k-1))*BE2A*sin(BETA/180*pi);
                BEZC(i,j,k,2) = i*0+(0.5+(j-1))*BE2B+k*0;         
                BE2A(i,j,k,2) = BE2A+i*0+j*0+k*0;
                BE2B(i,j,k,2) = BE2B+i*0+j*0+k*0;
                ANGLE(i,j,k,2) = BETA+i*0+j*0+k*0; 

            end

        end

    end
```

When I run this code, it appears that: "Assignment has more non-singleton rhs dimensions than non-singleton subscripts". The errors start from the line

- "`BEXC(i,j,k,1) = i*0+j*0+(0.5+(k-1))*BE2A*cos(BETA/180*pi)`"

Comment: The error message is pretty self-explanatory. `BEXC(i,j,k,1)` is one index and `i*0+j*0+(0.5+(k-1))*BE2A*cos(BETA/180*pi)` returns more than one number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
BE2A0 = 2*0.3048;
BE2B0 = 2*0.3048;
BETA0 = 0;

for i = 1:50

        for j = 1:i

            for k = 1:(i+1-j)

                % 1st quadrant
                BEXC(i,j,k,1) = i*0+j*0+(0.5+(k-1))*BE2A0*cos(BETA0/180*pi);
                BEYC(i,j,k,1) = i*0+j*0+(0.5+(k-1))*BE2A0*sin(BETA0/180*pi);
                BEZC(i,j,k,1) = i*0+(0.5+(j-1))*BE2B0+k*0;
                BE2A(i,j,k,1) = BE2A0+i*0+j*0+k*0;
                BE2B(i,j,k,1) = BE2B0+i*0+j*0+k*0;
                ANGLE(i,j,k,1) = BETA0+i*0+j*0+k*0;

                % 2nd quadrant
                BEXC(i,j,k,2) = i*0+j*0-(0.5+(k-1))*BE2A0*cos(BETA0/180*pi);
                BEYC(i,j,k,2) = i*0+j*0-(0.5+(k-1))*BE2A0*sin(BETA0/180*pi);
                BEZC(i,j,k,2) = i*0+(0.5+(j-1))*BE2B0+k*0;         
                BE2A(i,j,k,2) = BE2A0+i*0+j*0+k*0;
                BE2B(i,j,k,2) = BE2B0+i*0+j*0+k*0;
                ANGLE(i,j,k,2) = BETA0+i*0+j*0+k*0; 

            end

      end

end
```

Please change BE2A as BE2A0; BE2B as BE2B0;BETA as BETA0.

Answer (score 1):

Let's go through this:

1. I assume `BETA` changes, but you have left it out for clarity. If not, `BETA` is always `0`, thus you can substitute `cos(BETA/180*pi)` and `sin(BETA/180*pi)` with `1` and `0` respectively.

   a. Check out [`cosd()`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cosd.html) and [`sind()`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sind.html)
2. You multiply a lot of terms by zero. Skip those for clarity.

And then over to your problem. In the following two lines, you are assigning the value `BE2A` to both `BE2A(i,j,k,1)` and `BE2A(i,j,k,2)`. By doing this, you are creating a matrix `BE2A` with size `[i, j, k, 2]` (note the `2`).

```
BE2A(i,j,k,1) = BE2A+i*0+j*0+k*0;
BE2A(i,j,k,2) = BE2A+i*0+j*0+k*0;
```

In the next iteration, `k = 2`, you have:

```
BEXC(i,j,k,1) = i*0+j*0+(0.5+(k-1))*BE2A*cos(BETA/180*pi);
```

Now, `BE2A` is matrix with size: `[1, 1, 1, 2]`. You are multiplying this term by a bunch of scalars, thus ending up with a matrix, not a single number. The index `BEXC(i,j,k,1)` is obviously a single number, this you have a mismatch.

I'm assuming there's a lot more going on in this loop. If this is all there is,  then there are a lot of ways to improve it:

- [Don't have growing loops](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/preallocating-arrays.html)
- [Don't use `i` and `j` as variable names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab)
- Don't use loops at all. You can probably vectorize the whole thing